# How do I use javascript variable to filter Model in cshtml

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a javascript function that will calculate and return a status, then I want to use it to filter my model. But it seem it doesn't allow me to do this in cshtml file.

```
    var status = GetStatus();

    if (status != 'All')
    {
        data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Where(p => p.ConfirmedStatus == status))); 
    }
    else
    {
        data = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model));
    }
```

Comment: Not answering your question, but you seem new so this might help: `data = (status == 'All' ? @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)) : @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Where(p => p.ConfirmedStatus == status))` just a general tip :)

Comment: @statue - His current way of processing cannot work.  The Razor/LINQ has to be processed on the server side.  His `GetStatus()` method is a JavaScript function and will not be processed until the page gets to the client.  At that point, there is no possible way to use a LINQ method as the page has already left the server.

Comment: Correct! I was totally absentminded when I typed this!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use JavaScript to filter model data that you passed to your View in this way.  The model data is bound to the view on the server, before it is sent to the client.  This means that you cannot use LINQ inside of a JavaScript function like you have posted above because the server is already done with the file and sent it on to the client.  After the model data is bound, the entire view is sent to the client which is where JavaScript is processed.

There are other options such as partial page rendering (making an AJAX call to get the filtered data back to the server) or you could look at some jQuery plugins that filter data inside of a table such as http://jquery-plugins.net/jquery-filter-table-plugin.  It really depends on your use case.